# ANDROID:- Google pay ACTION CHOOSER not working

Tags: android, payment, google-pay

Im trying to do a payment through the action chooser. In my i have given the URI and when i am clicking on paynow button it asking select payment applicatin like GPAY or PAYTM or WHATAPP when ever i clicks on GPAY it is not working. But when i tried with whatsapp it is working. please see my code do i miss anything ?i am attaching some images for the reference

whenever i clicks on "PAYNOW" button im calling below function:-

```
private void payUsingUpi(String name, String strupi, String strnote, String stramount) {
        Log.e("main ", "email "+name +"--upi--"+strupi+"--"+ strnote+"--"+stramount);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("upi://pay").buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("pa", strupi)
                .appendQueryParameter("pn", name)
                //.appendQueryParameter("mc", "")
                //.appendQueryParameter("tid", "02125412")
                //.appendQueryParameter("tr", "25584584")
                .appendQueryParameter("tn", strnote)
                .appendQueryParameter("am", stramount)
                .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
                //.appendQueryParameter("refUrl", "blueapp")
                .build();

        Intent upiPayIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        upiPayIntent.setData(uri);

        // will always show a dialog to user to choose an app
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with");
        chooser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);


        // check if intent resolves
        if(null != chooser.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())) {
            //startActivity(chooser);
            startActivityForResult(chooser, UPI_PAYMENT);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(PaymentActivity.this,"No UPI app found, please install one to continue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

it will opens the GPAY. but im trying to proceed the payment , after entering the UPI pin everything it showing the error message as

> Payment failed
>
> You have exceeded the maximum transaction amount set by your bank.
> im not able to take the screenshot.

Pay now button in APP
[image: Pay now button in APP]

Action chooser

[image]

it would be greatefull if anyone have any suggestions

Comment: Pranav MS if you got solution for this let me know please

Comment: @DheerajSinghBhadoria sure man

Answer (score 1):

Once I was facing this issue. I solved this by using Business UPI ID. You need to use a Business UPI ID (like UPI IDs from Google Pay Business App, Paytm PhonePe Business App etc.) to receive payments.