# Can I use PayPal thru GooglePay without PCI DSS level 1 compliance

Tags: javascript, paypal, progressive-web-apps, google-pay

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#direct) Google Pay reference, if we use DIRECT instead of PAYMENT_GATEWAY then we need to be Payments Card Industry (PCI) Data Security Standard (DSS) Level 1 compliant.

[image]

The same document goes on to state that if we're using PayPal via Google Pay then we should specify "DIRECT": -

[image]

So if we use PayPal via Google Pay do we have to be Level 1 compliant? I don't see why. We don't wish to decrypt anything on our servers.

Comment: check this . here it allow you to chose  any apps allows payment option.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639572/android-google-pay-action-chooser-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if we use DIRECT instead of PAYMENT_GATEWAY then we need to be Payments Card Industry (PCI) Data Security Standard (DSS) Level 1 compliant.

This only applies along with `type: "CARD"`. It does not apply to `type: "PAYPAL"`, as in that case the only card information (which may or may not exist as part of the PayPal transaction) is being handled by PayPal only.